# Force download of file from external url not open in new tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I am trying to download a file with JavaScript and not let it open in a new tab or window.

What I have so far is this:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = filename;
link.href = fileurl;
link.click();
```

I've been doing a fair bit of research about this but cannot find anything that works because the file is coming from a Google Signed URL which I have no control over and cannot modify headers for.

This has to happen in client side JavaScript/jQuery.

### Edit

It is actually dynamic so there can be X number of files, if I could get them all to download as a zip that would be even better.

```
for(var i=0; i<filenames.length; i++){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', filenames[i]);
    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            fileurl = this.responseText;
            
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = filenames[i];
            link.href = fileurl;
            link.click();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "url_to_get_download_urls");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the download action in different browsers? In the latest versions of Chrome, you cannot download cross-origin files (they have to be hosted on the same domain).

As well if the file doesn't change, have you tried hosting the file yourself and initiating the download?

edit: If you're trying to bundle the items into a zip for download, that would necessitate doing the initial download on your own server and zipping there.

Comment: CORS policy on the Google Signed URLs allows my domain so I think I should be able to download them. These can be very large files so for scalability cannot be saving them to my server and downloading from there it has to be client side.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan There are a few more items to try here https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa